# Loading user controls dynamically in Mainwindow when value in dropdown changes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a C# WPF application.I've a list of user controls UC1,UC2 and UC3 having a ViewModel for each.And all internally refer to another common user control called UCB.
And my App.xaml refers to MainWindow.xml

UCB has a dropdown list with names of different account types.

I need to programmatically show the user control in MainWindow depending upon the account type selected in the Base user control UCB.How do I achieve this please?

My thoughts so far:
May be I can instantiate all my user controls in MainWindow.xaml.cs file like this:

```
    UserControl uc1 = (UserControl)assembly.CreateInstance(string.Format("{0}.MyUC1", type.Namespace));
    UserControl uc2 = (UserControl)assembly.CreateInstance(string.Format("{0}.MyUC2", type.Namespace));   

userControls.Add("1", uc1);
userControls.Add("2", uc2);
```

and then use the MainWindow.xaml's content property to set the desired user control based on the dropdown value.

```
this.Content = userControls["1"];
```

But how do I access this content property inside ComboBox_SelectionChanged event in UCB control??

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch view based on `Dropdown` selection by adding a `ContentControl`/`ContentPresenter` Hope you have different ViewModel for your `UserControls`

For Example:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}">
   <ContentPresenter.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:UC1VM}">
                <Views:UC1/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:UC2VM}">
                <Views:UC2/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

In your `UCB` ViewModel you should have an Objact property like below,

```
 private object _CurrentViewModel;
 public object CurrentViewModel
 {
        get { return _CurrentViewModel; }
        set { _CurrentViewModel = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
 }
```

Now when you select an item from your `DropDown` create the corresponding `ViewModel` for the `View` to be shown. and assign the `CurrentViewModel` to your newely created `ViewModel`. which will display your desired `View`

Comment: Thanks Abin for your inputs.And how do I load a default control in the MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: You can do that by placing a Grid in your main window. create rows and columns and specify your default control to show up. you can keep your default control by `<Views:defaultControl DataContext="{binding defaultViewModel}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />`

Comment: Ok.Also, where do I place the content control code please?Is it in MainWindow?

Comment: Yes it should go along with MainWindow as where do you want to show different views based on your DropDown Selection.